# How to Extract unknown digits from String java

Tags: java, extract

I have a sentence in modal e.g. "Your balance is 29,2 euro" and I need to get a number and store it. But a number is dynamic. So don't know the exact value. It can be integer as well as decimal.
And then I need to compare this value (the one which has been stored) with the value on next page.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: You should use regex.

Comment: That's a little vague and lacks a lot of context but you might want to look into regular expressions etc. However, it feels like your design is off as it shouldn't be necessary to pull values out of strings for comparison reasons.

Comment: You should look into the Scanner class.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO :)

Given that your string is quite static and you want to find a value inside it, I'd recommend you use [Apache Commons' substringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). If you don't want to add an additional dependency then you could implement this method yourself, it looks something like this:

```
public static String substringBetween(String initial, String open, String close) {
  int start = str.indexOf(open) + open.length();
  int end = str.indexOf(close, start);
  return str.substring(start, end);
}
```

Then the following issue you'd have is that separating decimals by comma is not Java's standard, so `29,2` won't be resolved by `Double.valueOf` or `Double.parseDouble`. You will need to either:

- Replace comma with dot, this can be achieved by using `str.replaceAll(",", ".")`
- Use a [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). For example, default NumberFormat for France Locale is using a comma to separate decimals.

A final solution will look like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String initialString = "Your balance is 29,2 euro";
    
    double doubleValue = parseAsDouble(findValue(initialString));
    System.out.println(doubleValue);
  }

  private static String findValue(String initial) {
    return StringUtils.substringBetween(initial, "Your balance is ", " euro");
  }

  private static double parseAsDouble(String value) throws ParseException {
    return NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE)
        .parse(value)
        .doubleValue();
  }
```

As mentioned earlier, you could change the implementation of `findValue` to use `substring` or `regex` and the implementation of `parseAsDouble` to use `Double.parseDouble` after replacing comma with dot.